# Observer for Contact Form

Tags: event-observer, soap, contact-us

I need to pass information from the Magento Contact Form to a CRM system. I was wondering does anyone know if there is an observer that can be triggered to pass the form information to the CRM via the SOAP API?

Answer (score 7):

When using an observer for the event `controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_index_post` you can access the Post-Data via

```
public function controllerActionPostdispatchContactsIndexPost(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $data = $observer->getData();
    $post = $data['controller_action']->getRequest()->getPost();
}
```

To listen for the event create the those nodes in the config.xml of your Module:

`config/global/events/`

```
<controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_index_post>
    <observers>
        <company_modulename_controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_index_post>
            <class>company_modulename/observer</class>
            <method>controllerActionPostdispatchContactsIndexPost</method>
        </company_modulename_controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_index_post>
    </observers>
</controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_index_post>
```

Comment: It was helpful post

Comment: Hello Can you share this in detail with path where I need to create xml and post data file ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no particular event dispatched when the contact form is filled.

but there might be a default controller like

controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_index_post